# MPU does not protect memory access

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I want to use the Cortex-M3 MPU to protect the memory from unintended access. For this purpose I configured the MPU. But I did not get any exception at all. Other exceptions as BusFault, HardFault has been forced with appropriate "bad code".

The current initialization is

```
MPU->CTRL &= ~MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;       // disable MPU

MPU->RNR  = 0
MPU->RBAR = 0x20000000;
MPU->RASR = 0x03000019; // 0x03UL << (MPU_RASR_ATTRS_Pos+8) | (0x19UL << 0);

MPU->RNR  = 1;
MPU->RBAR = 0x8000000;  // read back as 0x8000001
MPU->RASR = 0x03000027; // 0x03UL << (MPU_RASR_ATTRS_Pos+8) | (0x27UL << 0); 

MPU->RNR  = 2;
MPU->RBAR = 0x40000000; // read back as 0x40000002
MPU->RASR = 0x13000039; // 0x13UL << (MPU_RASR_ATTRS_Pos+8) | (0x39UL << 0); 

SCB->SHCSR |= SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;  // Enable the memory fault exception

MPU->CTRL |= MPU_CTRL_PRIVDEFENA_Msk | MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;   // Enable MPU
```

Until now I can access all memory. Now I add a region to protect a region.

```
MPU->CTRL &= ~MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk; // disable MPU

MPU->RNR = 3;
MPU->RBAR = 0x20002000;  // read back as 0x20002003
MPU->RASR = 0x00000009;  // 0x00UL << (MPU_RASR_ATTRS_Pos+8) | (0x09UL << 0);

MPU->CTRL |= MPU_CTRL_PRIVDEFENA_Msk | MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk; // re-enable MPU
```

The region number 3 should hide all other MPU regions. Now the memory at 0x20002000 should not be accessible neither readable not writable. But I can still read and even write the memory at this address.

What can inhibit the memory protection in a NXP LPC1788 CPU?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on NXP's lpc1788? Can you please provide with the header file that has MPU registers mapped into it?  Bacuase the header file lpc178x_8x.h which is provided by the NXP doesnt have that mapping.

Comment: Hello. What I have tried to implement is, I have a font stored at 0xA1000000. And, a call for TEXT_SetFont(&calibri72) is made. When the execution comes to this line of code, goes in HardFault handler. So, it implies that I may have caused an access violation. The location 0xA1000000 is at Ext SDRAM. I have configured MPU with a single 4GB region with R/W Access Parameters. Even I am having tough time in understanding MPU

Comment: You have this region at 0x80000000. Is it necessary to read it back as 0x80000001?

Comment: @PrasadTandale Well table 843 in section 39.4.5.4 of the "LPC178x/7x User manual" states that the page number is read in the lower four bits.

Comment: okay thanks. Found that in Coretex M3 technical reference manual r1p1